# Which citation call-out style (e.g. Harvard, APA) does plainnat use?

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle

I am writing my master thesis and would like to know which citation call-out style `plainnat` uses. For example is it APA, Harvard, etc.?

Furthermore, I would like to show the surname of the author before the first name in the bibliography. This is how it is now: "George Alexandridis, Kathleen P Fuller...", but I would like it to be "Alexandridis George, Fuller Kathleen P...". Is there a way to do this?

My code is as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\bibliography{Library}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3):

The `plainnat` bibliography style, when used with the `natbib` citation management package, can create three [3!] separate citation call-out styles:

- If `natbib` is loaded with the option `numbers`, `plainnat` will generate numeric-style citation call-outs.
- If `natbib` is loaded with the option `super`, `plainnat` will generate superscript-style numeric citation call-outs.
- If `natbib` is loaded with the option `authoryear`, `plainnat` will generate authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Incidentally, both APA and Harvard are associated with authoryear-style citation call-outs. The formatted bibliographic entries that BibTeX generates when it use the `plainnat` bib style do not conform to APA rules.

To change the way an author's full name is formatted, from (say) "Kevin de Bruyne" to "de Bruyne, Kevin", I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and name the copied file, say, `plainnatrev.bst` ("rev" being short for "reversed"). Don't edit an original file of your TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the file `plainnatrev.bst`, locate the function called `format.names`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 216.)
- In the `format.names` function, locate the following line:

  ```
      { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
      { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  In case you're curious: the components `ll`, `ff`, `vv` and `jj` represent the surname, first name(s), "von", and junior components of a full name. Each "full name" is assumed to contain at least a surname component.
- Save the file `plainnatrev.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to also refresh the filename database of your TeX distribution as needed. If you have no idea what the preceding sentence means, I suggest you choose the first option.
- In your main tex file, change `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnatrev}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{af:3001,
  author  = "George Alexandridis and Kathleen P. Fuller",
  title   = "Thoughts",
  year    = 3001,
}
@misc{kdb:5001,
  author  = "Kevin de Bruyne and Lucas, Jr., Robert E.",
  title   = "Further thoughts",
  year    = 5001,
}
\end{filecontents}  

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnatrev}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{af:3001}, \citep{kdb:5001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico- I appreciate your help. Do you perhaps know if there is a way for plainnat to conform to APA style? I like the format of plainnat.

Comment: @pozzo - It would be an utterly pointless nightmare of a job to rewrite the `plainnat` style so that it conforms to APA formatting guidelines. If you must follow the APA formatting guidelines, just use a citation management package such as `apacite` and the associated `apacite.bst` bibliography style file.

Comment: I tried using the following (found it from another thread you have also answered to @Mico) so I do not have to change the \cite commands throughout my whole document. 

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\setlength\bibhang{0pt}


When I run this code, a page before my cover is created with the following "==" on it. It also messes up the format of my whole document by "centering" and reducing the margins of all paragraphs. Thanks.

Comment: @pozzo - Merely loading the `apacite` package instead of the `natbib` package has no effect on the widths or other properties of the document's margins -- and neither does the choice of bibliography style. You must be doing something else with your document, in addition to changing `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib} \bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} \bibliographystyle{apacite}`, to generate this problem behavior.

Comment: @mico- that is the only thing I have changed, so I am clueless with regards to what could cause the issue as I am also quite new to LatEX. If i were to post my code, would you mind having a look at it and help me spot the mistake please?

Comment: @pozzo -- Please post a new query, so that more people will see it and hopefully be in a position to answer it.